# Having problems with cocos2d and menus?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone

I'm having a problem with xcode when making a menu when using the cocos2d templates.
I put this code in:

```
if( (self=[super init]) ) {
    CCMenuItemImage *item = [CCMenuItemImage itemWithNormalImage:@"bug.png" selectedImage:@"bug.png" target:self selector:@selector(doThis:)];
    CCMenu *menu = [CCMenu menuWithItems:item, nil];
    [self addChild:menu];
}
return self;
-(void)doThis:(id)sender{}
```

I put the if statement in the -(id) init method in helloworldlayer.m.
If anyone can help that would be greatly appreciated. I'm having the problem where everything builds correctly, but the picture doesn't show. I have it copied to my resources, but when I build it, no picture is shown.

Comment: What problem are you having? Please describe it and what you have tried to fix it.

Comment: Did you add the image to your project ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set Position of CCMenu in your code as below

```
if( (self=[super init]) ) {
    CCMenuItemImage *item = [CCMenuItemImage itemWithxNormalImage:@"bug.png" selectedImage:@"bug.png" target:self selector:@selector(doThis:)];
    CCMenu *menu = [CCMenu menuWithItems:item, nil];
    menu.position = ccp(200,200);
    [self addChild:menu];
}
return self;
-(void)doThis:(id)sender{}
```

Comment: Thank you very much I looked that over and forgot to do that when I started. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try this once:

```
    CCSprite *sprite_1 = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"bug.png"];
    CCSprite *sprite_2 = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"bug.png"];

    CCMenuItemSprite * item = [CCMenuItemSprite itemWithNormalSprite:close_1
                                      selectedSprite:close_2
                                              target:self
                                            selector:@selector(doThis:) ];
     CCMenu *menu = [CCMenu menuWithItems:item, nil];
     [self addChild:menu];

     item.position = ccp(200,200); //Set position
```

Still not work, then put break point and confirm sprite is not nil.

Answer (score 0):

Merely copying the file from initial directory to the Resources folder in your Xcode project wouldnt work. You need to add it to your bundle resources. For that,

Drag the picture from your project's Resources folder and drop under the Resources folder on the Project navigator bar in xcode (on the left side). Make sure to check "**Add to Target**"